# jsoup- Search Form's URL not changing in post()

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm Developing a web crawler.
I need to insert some value into the input field of a form (for a search) and get the result programatically. The form has a post method and the action value is `"/SetReviewFilter#REVIEWS"`. 
But the problem is when I do the search from the website manually the URL of the website don't change.
I think the web page is self posting
[Here the link of the Webpage](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g304132-d5566134-Reviews-Forest_Rock_Garden_Resort-Anuradhapura_North_Central_Province.html)

I got no idea to how to implement this.But I tried this

```
private Document getReviewSearchDocument(Document search,String search_url)
    {
//search_url mean the url of that search document I fetched previously
// search means the current document of the webpage

    Element input = search.getElementsByClass("ratings_and_types").first();
        Element link = input.select("div:nth-child(1) > form ").first();
        Document rdocument= null;

        if (link !=null) {
            System.out.println("form found! on: "+link_value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Form not found");
        }
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(search_url + "/SetReviewFilter#REVIEWS").timeout(30 * 1000).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true);
        try {
            Connection.Response resp = connection.execute();

            if (resp.statusCode() ==200) {

                rdocument = connection.data("q",this.keywords).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36").execute().parse();
                System.out.println("Success: "+ resp.statusCode());
                System.out.println("document: "+ rdocument.text().toString());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("no search match");
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        return rdocument;
    }
```

If any body have a idea on this please share it.
Thank You.

Comment: If you want to get the search result , why are you using "SetReviewFilter"?

Comment: That's the value of the attribute "action" in that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few alternatives and modified my code to call a **JSOUP POST request** to get the job done.But I got failed several times due to the problems with cookies.I found that, for this single post request it requires almost 50 cookies(Thanks to Chrome console).And some cookies I couldn't fill it my self because those cookies were linked to different websites(eg: facebook).And the worst scenario is that I have to make this request depending on the number of hotels per city.So sometimes it can be up to 85 000 ,So it will be costly process.(-5  for me for didn't see that coming)

There for I rebuild the project through Web Automation using Selenium in Java.And the searching in forms became so easy.
Thank You!